# Width of div is not changing with window size even when specified in percentage?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following code inside a media query (from Bootstrap):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-9 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

When resizing the window between 768px and 992px, the width of my column is always 562.5px. The width of wrapping `div` with the `row` class is always 750px. Why is that? I always thought that specifying width in percent meant that the width of our element will always be 75%. For example, when window is 992px wide it would be 744px wide and when window is 768px wide it would be 576px wide.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you overwriting the css in your bootstrap library or creating a separate css file

Comment: No, I am not overwriting it and there is no separate file.

Comment: Make sure to include your custom css stylesheet after including your bootstrap cdn. That will override the bootstrap's css. Let me know if it workd

Comment: @Jagrati Yes, I have included my stylesheet after Bootstrap. Is it correct to assume that some other wrapper is making the container fixed width?

Comment: What happens when you inspect the div? While resizing the browser window you should see the width changing and what media queries are applied

Comment: what do you have in your meta viewport? <meta name="viewport" ... >

Comment: In your code you defined main wrapping div as `container` which has a constant width. You should  deifne it as `<div class="container-fluid">`. then it will depend on screen dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because *bootstrap*'s own rule set the container to a fixed width, which also is not the same as its `min-width` rule value.

```
/* bootstrap rules */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;                /*  75% of 750px = 562.5px  */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;                /*  75% of 970px = 727.5px  */
  }
}
```

If you want it to change while resizing the viewport, you could like this

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/mwwkruzn/)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Or, if you want it to be fluid all the time, simply change the `container` class to `container-fluid`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/mwwkruzn/1/)